# Como acceder a los datos dentro de una lista múltiple en kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, clase, android-recyclerview

**Introducción:**

Me encuentro creando un recycler view con dos tipos de vistas diferentes ("Day" y "Notification"), para lo cual estoy usando un model con una doble data class:

**Model:**

```
open class NotificationsViewTypes() {
    open fun isDay() : Boolean = false
    open fun isNotification() : Boolean = false
}

data class ViewDay(val day: String) : NotificationsViewTypes(){
    override fun isDay(): Boolean = true
}

data class ViewNotification(val urlPhoto: String?, val userName: String?, val notification: 
String?, val notificationTime: String?): NotificationsViewTypes(){

    override fun isNotification(): Boolean = true
}
```

Los datos los obtengo a través de un Object...

**Multiple Data Object:**

```
object MultipleData {

fun multipleList():List<NotificationsViewTypes>{
    val mutableList= mutableListOf<NotificationsViewTypes>()
    mutableList.add(
        ViewDay(
        "Today"
        )
    )
    mutableList.add(
        ViewNotification(
        "https://expertphotography.b-cdn.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/profile-photos-4.jpg"
        , "María Constanza", "ha comenzado a seguirte.", "19:33h"
        )
    )

    return mutableList.toList()
}
}
```

**Array que envío a el adapter:**

```
val arrayListNotifications: ArrayList<NotificationsViewTypes>
```

**Mi pregunta:**

Como puedo acceder a los datos de la data class "ViewDay" o de "ViewNotification" mediante código, para poder usar dichos datos en el adaptador del recycler?

Probé con el siguiente código pero no me lleva a ningún lado :(

```
val urlPhoto: String? = arrayListNotifications[vh.adapterPosition].
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo podràs obtener `isDay()` o `isNotification()` ya que estas definiendo el `ArrayList` de elementos tipo `NotificationsViewTypes`

Cambia el `ArrayList` a tipo `ViewNotification` y creas tu `ArrayList` de esta forma:

```
    val arrayListNotifications: ArrayList<ViewNotification>
    arrayListNotifications = multipleList() as ArrayList<ViewNotification>
```

aquì podràs sin problema obtener el valor de la url de la foto usando la posiciòn (`vh.adapterPosition`) en el adapter:

```
    val urlPhoto: String? = arrayListNotifications.get(vh.adapterPosition).urlPhoto
    println("urlPhoto: " + urlPhoto)
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, @Elenasys . El problema es que aplicando lo que mencionas, seguiría estando en la misma situación ya que tendría acceso a ViewNotification pero no a ViewDay. Recordemos que este es un recyclerView con doble layout :(

Comment: Lo que sucede es que NotificationsViewTypes, ViewDay y ViewNotification son clases diferentes, por qué no haces mejor solo un tipo que tenga los métodos para acceder a ellos

Comment: gracias nuevamente. Podrías por favor darme un ejemplo de una data class la cual me permita enviar 2 tipos distintos de datos, asi como muestro en "Multiple Data Object"? No se me ocurre como resolver este problema